# Google Geocoding API Licensing

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm building an application and I need to get the coordinates based on address, so I'm planning to use the Google Geocoding API. As I read in the Geocoding reference https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat I may store the data to avoid exceed the limit.

However, my application it's not a map based, I mean, has no map in my application and I just need the coordinates (latitude and longitude) to fulfill an own system that get some store information within a radius from coordinates.

Could I use the Google Geocoding API for this purpose? Is it allowed by licensing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and not coding

Comment: No, but you could use a Similar API to Google: https://www.geocode.farm/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846) for details.

Answer (score 2):

> 10.1.1 (h) **No Use of Content without a Google Map.** You must not use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation. In any event, you must not use or display the Content on or in conjunction with a non-Google map. **For example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service in conjunction with a non-Google map.** As another example, you must not display Street View imagery alongside a non-Google map, but you may display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation explicitly permits you to do so.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: I saw this part of the licensing but my application dosen't have any map, I think I can't use the google information in maps like bing or yahoo, but maybe I may use without any map. By the way, the geocode.farm it's perfect for me. Thank you!

Comment: What part of *"No Use of Content without a Google Map."* is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Though the general terms disallow use of content without a Google map, I think the specific terms for the Geocoding API permit it.

> The following terms apply only to the Geocoding API:
>
> 3.1 Use without a Google Map. Customer may use Google Maps Content from the Geocoding API in Customer Applications without a corresponding Google Map.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms#3.-geocoding-api